# Drupal 7: assigning custom created user role to newly created user AS DEFAULT

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, account

I need newly created users to be assigned to a particular role as default.

as default, a new user automatically assigned as "**authenticated user**" I also need as "**content admin** (custom created role)"

any idea how to do that?

appreciate helps!!

---

*Why I need that?*

*I create a content admin role for client, I dont give administrator access. and they need the ability to create new users as content admin. as default I need to give access to "administer permission", but by this way they can create administrator user as well :/ and can messed up with the site. So, if I can assign content-admin role as default to new created users, i wont give administer permissions access to client.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the module [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole).  It allows you to automatically assign roles to new users.  You can also set different role presets depending if a user registered himself or an admin created the account.  Currently it is only in dev for Drupal 7, but from the issue queue it seems to be in working condition.

From the project page:

> The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes. The first is to
>   provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is
>   created. The second is to allow the end user the option of choosing
>   their own role or roles when they create their account. The third is
>   to provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is
>   created. The administrator has full control over these functions and
>   can have them working together or independently of each other. Auto
>   Assign Role is integrated with the Content Profile module so that you
>   can have content types serving as registration pages. You can even
>   replace the default user/register page with a customized version of
>   your own design.

Comment: In order to have an administer created page automatically be assigned a role, you have to enable access for them to edit permissions.